# Adobe flash player how to play MP4 or AAC File

Tags: flash, mp4

I have a question about how to use flash player to play mp4 or aac.

the mp4's or aac's data in the memory, I haven't any URL or File directory. Adobe's API "Netstream.Appendbytes" can't load mp4 file. so I tried to use the C++ to convert MP4 to FLV and use Flascc compiler it, but I found a problem that mp4's Audio Sample rate is bigger than flv, for example sample rate 48K。

the second It's very large size than as3'code which throgh Flacc compile it.

so I want to konw, is any open source about it or tell me how to use Netstream.Appendbytes play mp4 please.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the NetStream class. It is a class intended to play videos and does work with MP4 (you might be out of luck with AAC though, it may be protected by proprietary encoding.)

```
var stream:NetStream = new NetStream(new NetConnection('myvideo.mp4'));
stream.play();
```

help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html

Comment: thank you very much, but The data is in the memory, I can not use any file directory.